# Java Server , processing Json files

Tags: java, json, tomcat, httpwebrequest

I have a mobile application that makes http post requests and sends a json file.

I would like to create a server in java that the only thing it does is get this json file and store it in my database. The problem is that i never wrote any server side code and have no clue how to do that.

How can i create a java server that all it does is wait for a json file to arrive and then process it (like storing it to my database etc..)

Bill

Comment: Please first read some tutorials of Apache tomcat and java server technologies like servlet, jsp's ans web services.

Comment: Ok but where to start from? Do you have a simple tutorial on how to make this ? Or a simple java Server/Client to exchange a simple json file?